# Is there coding convention for better place of 'coll' and 'n' for Clojure?

Tags: clojure, coding-style, conventions

While I write clojure code, I'm confused about when to follow `(func coll n)` format and `(func n coll)` format.
In Clojure/core,
`(take n coll)` is used while `(nth coll n)`is also right code. Also, there are `(reduce func n coll)`, `(get coll n)`, and `(drop n coll)`.
Is there any rule/convention for right place of argument type while defining these confusing functions? Or should I just type `doc` everytime without sense?

Comment: i try to put "configuring" params left, so it makes use of `partial` easier.

Comment: @cfrick: could you expand on your comment in an answer, please? I'd like to understand the thinking behind this I've never gotten the hang of `partial` and perhaps this would help me. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis, given a function `f` that takes *n* arguments, `(partial f an-arg)` returns a function that takes *n*-1 arguments.  The new function is like `f` but with the first argument already set to `an-arg`.  Suppose I have a sequence of sequences named `xss`, and I want a new sequence that's similar but includes only the first two elements of each of the inner sequences.  I can do this: `(map #(take 2 %) xss)` or I can use `partial`: `(map (partial take 2) xss)`.  Giving `partial` more arguments works similarly.  Like cfrick, I try to put parameters first that facilitate use of `partial`.

Comment: burrown, I don't like `nth`'s syntax.   I often have a complex expression in the `coll` place, while `n` is usually simple, but then it's buried at the end of the long `call` expression and is difficult to notice.  I also often go back and forth between `take` and `nth` with the same parameters at the repl, which means rearranging the entire expression.  As  a result, instead of `nth` I often use a function I've defined that simply reverses the arguments of `nth`.  I call it `thn`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it depends. Perhaps the core library actually best exemplifies this. If you look at the examples you cited:

```
(take n coll) 
(drop n coll)
```

In both these cases, semantically, the most important thing is how many elements you are taking/dropping.

In the case of something like `(get coll n)`, there's a left-to-right semantic of first having a collection before having an index with which to fetch. I think `nth` is the same in this regard. Note, there are other ways to get indexed elements from a collection - for example you can also just do this:

`(coll n)`

This works because clojure data-structures like `vector`, `hash-map` and `set` can all act as functions. IMO, this is a more confusing way to accomplish the same thing as it is often harder to read and does not show intent nearly as clearly as `(get coll n)`.

In the end I think what makes the most intuitive sense to the caller is probably best and will make your code the most readable/maintainable by future users of your code.

There are other considerations. For example, variable-arity use cases (e.g. using `& more`), where you will need the required arguments to come first to prevent ambiguity. I would still consider readability first however, as variable argument functions *can* come with their own readability issues. See this great [post](http://stuartsierra.com/2015/06/01/clojure-donts-optional-arguments-with-varargs) from Stuart Sierra which talks about this.

Answer (score 3):

The `(func ... coll)` format is used for the sequence library: `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, &c. The intervening arguments are more often functions than numbers.

The `(func coll n)` format is used to select elements from the collection, using `nth` for a `seq`able collection or `get` (which may be omitted) from an associative collection.